# MATLAB: Symbolic Toolbox Plotting versus Discreet Plotting

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm wondering if anyone has any insight into why these two plot commands produce domains that are orders of magnitude different?

```
syms t
x1Axis = 0:.01:10;
fun1(t) = sin(t)
plot(sin(x1Axis))
hold on
y = sin(x1Axis)
plot(x1Axis, y)
```

`fun1(t)` is plotted "symbolically" while `y` is evaluated and plotted "discreetly". Should I be using a different plot method in the case of the first function?

Answer (score 2):

No, you are not plotting the symbolic function correctly.

In your code, the instruction `plot(sin(x1Axis))` is not a symbolic plot, but a numeric plot of the sine versus the index of each value.

From the [`plot` documentation page](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html):

> `plot(Y)` creates a 2-D line plot of the data in `Y` versus the index of
>   each value.
>
> - If `Y` is a vector, then the x-axis scale ranges from `1` to `length(Y)`.

To plot the symbolic function use [`fplot`](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fplot.html).

The following example will allow you to see that both the symbolic and numeric plots are the same:

```
xmin = 0;
xmax = 10;

% Symbolic Plot.
syms t
fun1(t) = sin(t);
fplot(fun1, [xmin xmax], '-r');

hold on;

% Numeric Plot.
x = xmin:.01:xmax;
y = sin(x);
plot(x, y, '--g');

% Add legend.
legend('Symbolic Plot', 'Numeric Plot', 'Location', 'north');
```

This is the result:

[image: Sine: Symbolic and Numeric plot]